# Warning about hiding member variables?

Tags: c++, gcc

The following code snippet has a memory leak that I spent too much time chasing down. The problem is that inside Foo(), the local variable x_ hides the member variable x_.  It's quite annoying too, because the compiler could have warned me about it.  Is there a flag in GCC for such a warning?  (For the curious: I have arrived at the buggy code by first using a local variable, then changing it to a member variable, but forgetting to remove the type declaration.)

```
struct A {
  A() x_(NULL) {}

  ~A() {
    delete x_;
  }

  void Foo() {
    HugeThingy* x_ = new HugeThingy();
    x_->Bar("I. Need. Garbage. Collection. Now.");
  }

  HugeThingy* x_;

  DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(A);  // Macro to prevent copy/assign.
}
```

Comment: Several people have mentioned that you should just use a plain string object rather than a pointer and dynamic allocation -- and they're right. If (as I suspect) you actually want to know how to get the compiler to warn you when you declare a local variable that hides a member variable, I'd suggest clarifying your question.

Comment: As you have the pointer as member variable please remember to provide Copy constructor and Assignment operator.

Comment: If not provide them, then at least suppress the defaults.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use -Wshadow.

By the way, neither -W nor -Wall enables -Wshadow.

It's nice to have the compiler help avoid this kind of problem, but that won't even be necessary if you use conventions that help avoid creating it in the first place, such reserving names of the form `x_` for member variables, not local variables.

Comment: It appears to me that OP has such a convention, but has had a "thinko" and typed "string* x_ =" instead of the "x_ =" that was actually intended.

Comment: IMHO, it's far better to have your editor highlight local and member variables in contrasting ways than it is to add a hungarian wart to the name.

Comment: @rmeador.  I'm sorry but that is a pretty dangerous statement.  If you ever need to write code that is to be ported to other platforms, you simply cannot trust that all editors will do this.  It's always best to write code that is as robust as you can make it.

Comment: The sad thing is that neither `-Wextra` enables this warning. One is just supposed to know that it exists and use it. Maybe we need something like `-Wextra2` ?

Answer (score 4):

FWIW I wouldn't have this problem because I use a naming convention to distinguish member data from local variables: my member data identifiers are invariably prefixed with `m_`.

Comment: It is also not uncommon convention for private member functions. It helps to catch quick and clearly in a second what's private.

Comment: And nobody working on the code has ever made a copy & paste error? Wow.

Answer (score 0):

We use these warts on the beginnings of names -
a_ argument
d_ data member
s_ static data in class
f_ static data in file

... and no wart for local variables.

Truly, the Lakos book is your friend.