# Member variables and method variables for conflicting names

Tags: c++, oop

A question about c++ classes.  I have some code which has various classes in it.  In one class it has a member, double temp.  But in one of the class methods there is the definition: double temp as well.
I dont get any compiler errors or even warnings so I assume there is some default behaviour in this sort of situation?  Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: @JohnDibling: We don't need code. And this is not a general question.

Comment: IMO this question is reasonable.

Comment: @Sean:  That was almost 4 years ago.  Things here were much different back then.  In any case, I've re-read the question and decided I jumped the gun here.  c/v reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Scoping rules** dictate how the compiler will look up variables names.

In your case the local `temp` is hidding the member variable `temp`, so all references to `temp` will resolve to your local `temp`.

To get around this use the `this` pointer to explicitly get the member variable:

```
this->temp = .... // member variable
temp = .... // local variable
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it works:

```
struct Foo
{
   double temp;

   void bar()
   {
      double temp;       // "hides" the member
      temp = 3.0;        // assigns to the local
      this->temp = 5.0;  // assigns to the member
   }

   void baz()
   {
      temp = 3.0;        // assigns to the member
      this->temp = 5.0;  // assigns to the member
   }
};
```

[The flag `-Wshadow` turns on a warning for this, in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/911740/560648).

Answer (score 2):

The innermost `temp` will be used by default.

If you want to access the class member then use `this->temp`.

Many C++ programmers observe a conventional prefix `m_` for all class data members.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I may feel a little uneasy in that case if our firms were to merge ;-)

Comment: I don't merge with firms that continue to uphold Hungarian-ish notation from the late 1750s :)

Answer (score 1):

Variables defined in an narrower scope hide those defined above them. Some compilers do issue warnings about this (are you compiling with `-Wall`?)

Comment: `-Wall` doesn't include `-Wshadow`.