# Initialize array of vectors where each vector is size 0

Tags: c++

I have a class `Thing` with a constructor `Thing::Thing()` and a method `Thing::print()`. I am trying to create `arrayOfVectors` such that each std::vector within the array is of size 0. The constructor function prints out the sizes of each vector correctly but the `print()` method does not.

I have tried calling `arrayOfVectors[n].clear()` and `arrayOfVectors[n].assign(0,0)` on each vector within the array but did not work.

`Thing.hpp`

```
class Thing {
private:
  std::vector<int>* arrayOfVectors;

public:
  Thing();
  void print() const;
};
```

`Thing.cpp`

```
Thing::Thing() {
  std::vector<int> arrayOfVectors[5];
  std::cout << arrayOfVectors[0].size() << std::endl; // 0
  std::cout << arrayOfVectors[1].size() << std::endl; // 0
  std::cout << arrayOfVectors[2].size() << std::endl; // 0
  std::cout << arrayOfVectors[3].size() << std::endl; // 0
  std::cout << arrayOfVectors[4].size() << std::endl; // 0
}

void Thing::print() const {
  std::cout << arrayOfVectors[0].size() << std::endl; // 0
  std::cout << arrayOfVectors[1].size() << std::endl; // 35183230189065
  std::cout << arrayOfVectors[2].size() << std::endl; // 33
  std::cout << arrayOfVectors[3].size() << std::endl; // 35
  std::cout << arrayOfVectors[4].size() << std::endl; // 108
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
int main() {
  Thing thing;
  thing.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you assigning arrayofvectors to something?

Comment: @kingW3 It's at `std::vector<int> arrayOfVectors[5];`. There was a typo.

Comment: `std::vector<int> arrayOfVectors[5];` creates a local variable in the constructor that no longer exists when the constructor finishes. This does not have any connection to the class member with the same name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring a local variable within class scope with same name as a class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494407/declaring-a-local-variable-within-class-scope-with-same-name-as-a-class-attribut)

Comment: `arrayOfVectors` is a pointer that is not initialized when you call print()

Comment: That's not the right way to assign it or create it, perhaps use a vector of vectors instead? Good way to avoid having to deal with new and delete.

Comment: `*` marks a pointer, Try `std::array<std::vector<int>, 5u> aov;` instead and read the linked question/answers as well as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Thing::Thing() {
>   std::vector<int> store[5];
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

This here is an array of vectors. It is an automatic variable. Automatic variables are destroyed at the end of the block where they were created. In this case, the local array is destroyed at the end of the constructor call.

> ```
> class Thing {
> private:
>   std::vector<int>* arrayOfVectors;
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

This here is a pointer to a vector. It is not an array. It is a member variable of the class `Thing`. It is a completely separate variable from the local `store` variable.

Your constructor never initializes the member variable, so when you indirect the pointer in the `print` member function, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

If you want your class to have an array as a member variable, you can write it like this:

```
class Thing {
private:
  std::vector<int> arrayOfVectors[5];
```

You don't need to declare a constructor, since the automatically generated one does exactly what you want - all vectors will be empty.

---

> How can i avoid setting a specific number like 5 in the header definition?

You cannot avoid that with an array variable. The size must be known at the time of compilation. If you need an array with non-fixed size, you need to allocate the array in the dynamic storage. The idiomatic way to create a dynamic array is to use `std::vector`:

```
class Thing {
private:
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vectorOfVectors{5};
```

Comment: How can i avoid setting a specific number like `5` in the header definition?

Comment: after declaring the vectorOfVectors in the header, how do you assign std::vector<std::vector<int>> to vectorOfVectors in the constructor definition

Comment: @Senyokbalgul you don't need to assign anything to `vectorOfVectors` if you use a default member initializer like I've shown in my answer (nor do you need to declare a constructor).

Comment: But don't use 2D vectors.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why not?

Comment: Because they're poison for your cache and introduce a totally unnecessary second layer of indirections and dynamic allocations

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit without knowing what OP is using their vectors for, how can you tell that the second layer is unnecessary?

Comment: We can't know for sure but the use cases for it are an order of magnitude rarer than its actual use.