# Pointer code smell C++

Tags: c++, pointers, gsl

I'm using the gsl library in C++. I have declared a gsl_vector pointer mesh as a private member of the class.

```
private:
    gsl_vector * mesh;
```

I also have a method, MeshBuilder, that declares a gsl_vector, pointer mesh (over-riding the original mesh variable) and returns mesh.

```
gsl_vector * ThinFilm::LinearMesh(...){
    gsl_vector * mesh = gsl_vector_alloc(numberofcells);
    ...
    return mesh;
}
```

I then assign the result of the method to the variable mesh as:

```
mesh = MeshBuilder(...);
```

It compiles and runs just fine (no warnings either, with -Wall). Stepping through the program I noticed that the variable mesh is assigned an address, and then the MeshBuilder overwrites that. Which is exactly what I programmed to do.

But is it good practice? After all, shouldn't I not assign a value to the pointer address?

Shouldn't I instead not declare a the mesh pointer in the MeshBuilder method and therefore directly use the pointer declared in the private section of the class?

I'm guessing the only reason this works is because the address value I'm assigning to mesh is in fact valid having been declared.

Comment: *I noticed that the variable mesh is assigned an address,* -- Who assigned the address?  Or is it just an uninitialized pointer?

Comment: Name hiding might be surprising.

Comment: You talk about a method called `MeshBuilder` but you showed us other method: `LinearMesh`...

Comment: @Rama Sorry I intended to ask for the MatrixBuilder but the MeshBuilder does exactly the same thing. So thnx for whoever edited the question to consistently say MeshBuilder.

Comment: @Jarod42 is there a compiler flag that will warn me of name hiding?

Comment: `-Wshadow` from [warning-about-hiding-member-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911740/warning-about-hiding-member-variables).

Answer (score 2):

The mesh variable in the method shadows the private's variable. 
If you use the private variable directly, then you avoid declaring a temporary, but in practice, it does not change much.

However, if the interface of the class is to be used in multithreaded contexts, then changing the private variable directly will make it visible to any other thread at the *allocation* time, so if the `...` section in the code above does some sort of setup of the vector, it means other thread might see or use an invalid (not constructed) variable.
In that case, you should use a temporary (like in your initial code) and protect the assignment `mesh = MeshBuilder(...)` with either a mutex or an atomic operation (like CAS, or pointer exchange).

Also, in all cases, if you want to write safe code, you should also consider what is going to happen is an exception is thrown in the `...` part of the code.
Setting the private variable directly, you might have a chance to clean the allocation (in the destructor of your class), else you'll get a memory leak since a pointer does not clean the allocation by itself.

If you want a really safe code that's working in all possible conditions, you should use a smart pointer in place of the temporary (for exception safe code), a mutex to protect private variable access (for multithread safe code).

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is no, in your current code, you are leaking a resource.
The problem is `gsl_vector_alloc` does not return a value, but indeed an address, which point to a struct that contain the value you except to see. In this context, `gsl_vector_alloc` is behaving similar to using `new`, as it allocating a vector struct, and initializing it.

The function `gsl_vector_alloc`, as it name suggest allocate a vector. This mean you need to free it with `gsl_vector_free` before you are overriding it.
Also allocation can fail, in such a case `gsl_vector_alloc` will return `NULL` and you will have to check for it, before using mesh.

Side note: In the function you are providing you call your local variable mesh, which has the same name as a private member, this is a bad practice as the local variable will hide the private member.